# can't convert json to java pojo classes?

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I would like to convert this JSON to make a list and insert in RecyclerView but I can't because it gives me 3 classes.
So how do I convert this class to make a parent class; can anyone help me so that I can make a list of responses to put into RecyclerView.

```
[
    {
        "id": 114,
        "name_ar": "محمصه زين",
        "latitude": null,
        "longitude": null,
        "name_en": "Mohamsa Zein",
        "description_ar": "",
        "description_en": "",
        "phone": null,
        "mobile": "01110881085",
        "address_ar": "مدينتى، Egypt",
        "address_en": "مدينتى، Egypt",
        "photo": "5b7958dc1c3661534679260.jpg",
        "album": null,
        "created_at": {
            "date": "2018-08-19 11:47:40.000000",
            "timezone_type": 3,
            "timezone": "UTC"
        },
        "updated_at": {
            "date": "2018-10-23 11:00:22.000000",
            "timezone_type": 3,
            "timezone": "UTC"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 184,
        "name_ar": "محل عصائر فيرتاس",
        "latitude": null,
        "longitude": null,
        "name_en": "Varieties For Juice",
        "description_ar": "",
        "description_en": "",
        "phone": null,
        "mobile": "01024229935",
        "address_ar": "مدينتى، Egypt",
        "address_en": "مدينتى، Egypt",
        "photo": null,
        "album": null,
        "created_at": {
            "date": "2018-10-28 11:40:54.000000",
            "timezone_type": 3,
            "timezone": "UTC"
        },
        "updated_at": {
            "date": "2019-01-02 08:36:04.000000",
            "timezone_type": 3,
            "timezone": "UTC"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: What do you mean by three(3) classes? its an array with two objects on it.

Comment: Would you please provide the information of your class?

Comment: @MetaSnarf when i try to convert it on this website it gaves me 3 classes try it ! http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/

Comment: it will give you Three classes as one is of the whole response and other two are of **created_at** and **updated_at**

Comment: @RakshitNawani yeah i know, what i need to do is to make a parent class give me the whole response ! any idea how to do that !

Comment: I create my own Response classes using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ you can custome it as you like try it

Comment: I recommend this plugin for your android studio: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7654-gsonformat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My Approach on this would be this:

Using GSON library.

I create 2 model classes

1. the main class that would contain info of each array item
2. a custom date class that would contain your date info for the
   `created_at` and the `updated_at` properties

   `class MyDate{
        public String date;
        public int timezone_type;
        public String timezone
   }`

   `class Info{
       public String id;
       public String name_ar;
       ..//other properties//..
       public MyDate created_at;
       public MyDate updated_at;
   }`

then parse the json to an array list of Info class

```
List<Info> infoArray = new Gson().fromJson(stringJson, new TypeToken<List<Info>>(){}.getType());
```

Comment: how to make the parent array which contains id and name .. ect !

Comment: @MohamedElFwakhry If you Response class name is Info then pass it as List<Info>

Comment: @MohamedElFwakhry, the parent array would be the `Info` class. Note that it contains a property `created_at` and `updated_at` of `MyDate` class type.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly i believe this is what you mean. Kindly use this

```
public  class TestRequest {

    private UpdatedAtEntity updatedAt;
    private CreatedAtEntity createdAt;
    private String photo;
    private String addressEn;
    private String addressAr;
    private String mobile;
    private String descriptionEn;
    private String descriptionAr;
    private String nameEn;
    private String nameAr;
    private int id;

    public UpdatedAtEntity getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(UpdatedAtEntity updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    public CreatedAtEntity getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(CreatedAtEntity createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public String getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    public void setPhoto(String photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }

    public String getAddressEn() {
        return addressEn;
    }

    public void setAddressEn(String addressEn) {
        this.addressEn = addressEn;
    }

    public String getAddressAr() {
        return addressAr;
    }

    public void setAddressAr(String addressAr) {
        this.addressAr = addressAr;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getDescriptionEn() {
        return descriptionEn;
    }

    public void setDescriptionEn(String descriptionEn) {
        this.descriptionEn = descriptionEn;
    }

    public String getDescriptionAr() {
        return descriptionAr;
    }

    public void setDescriptionAr(String descriptionAr) {
        this.descriptionAr = descriptionAr;
    }

    public String getNameEn() {
        return nameEn;
    }

    public void setNameEn(String nameEn) {
        this.nameEn = nameEn;
    }

    public String getNameAr() {
        return nameAr;
    }

    public void setNameAr(String nameAr) {
        this.nameAr = nameAr;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public static class UpdatedAtEntity {
        private String timezone;
        private int timezoneType;
        private String date;

        public String getTimezone() {
            return timezone;
        }

        public void setTimezone(String timezone) {
            this.timezone = timezone;
        }

        public int getTimezoneType() {
            return timezoneType;
        }

        public void setTimezoneType(int timezoneType) {
            this.timezoneType = timezoneType;
        }

        public String getDate() {
            return date;
        }

        public void setDate(String date) {
            this.date = date;
        }
    }

    public static class CreatedAtEntity {
        private String timezone;
        private int timezoneType;
        private String date;

        public String getTimezone() {
            return timezone;
        }

        public void setTimezone(String timezone) {
            this.timezone = timezone;
        }

        public int getTimezoneType() {
            return timezoneType;
        }

        public void setTimezoneType(int timezoneType) {
            this.timezoneType = timezoneType;
        }

        public String getDate() {
            return date;
        }

        public void setDate(String date) {
            this.date = date;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TestRequest{" +
                "updatedAt=" + updatedAt +
                ", createdAt=" + createdAt +
                ", photo='" + photo + '\'' +
                ", addressEn='" + addressEn + '\'' +
                ", addressAr='" + addressAr + '\'' +
                ", mobile='" + mobile + '\'' +
                ", descriptionEn='" + descriptionEn + '\'' +
                ", descriptionAr='" + descriptionAr + '\'' +
                ", nameEn='" + nameEn + '\'' +
                ", nameAr='" + nameAr + '\'' +
                ", id=" + id +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create pojo class like this.

```
public abstract class TempClass {

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("updated_at")
    private UpdatedAt updatedAt;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("created_at")
    private CreatedAt createdAt;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("photo")
    private String photo;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("address_en")
    private String addressEn;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("address_ar")
    private String addressAr;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("mobile")
    private String mobile;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("description_en")
    private String descriptionEn;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("description_ar")
    private String descriptionAr;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("name_en")
    private String nameEn;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("name_ar")
    private String nameAr;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("id")
    private int id;

    public UpdatedAt getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(UpdatedAt updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    public CreatedAt getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(CreatedAt createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public String getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    public void setPhoto(String photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }

    public String getAddressEn() {
        return addressEn;
    }

    public void setAddressEn(String addressEn) {
        this.addressEn = addressEn;
    }

    public String getAddressAr() {
        return addressAr;
    }

    public void setAddressAr(String addressAr) {
        this.addressAr = addressAr;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getDescriptionEn() {
        return descriptionEn;
    }

    public void setDescriptionEn(String descriptionEn) {
        this.descriptionEn = descriptionEn;
    }

    public String getDescriptionAr() {
        return descriptionAr;
    }

    public void setDescriptionAr(String descriptionAr) {
        this.descriptionAr = descriptionAr;
    }

    public String getNameEn() {
        return nameEn;
    }

    public void setNameEn(String nameEn) {
        this.nameEn = nameEn;
    }

    public String getNameAr() {
        return nameAr;
    }

    public void setNameAr(String nameAr) {
        this.nameAr = nameAr;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public static class UpdatedAt {
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("timezone")
        private String timezone;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("timezone_type")
        private int timezoneType;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("date")
        private String date;

        public String getTimezone() {
            return timezone;
        }

        public void setTimezone(String timezone) {
            this.timezone = timezone;
        }

        public int getTimezoneType() {
            return timezoneType;
        }

        public void setTimezoneType(int timezoneType) {
            this.timezoneType = timezoneType;
        }

        public String getDate() {
            return date;
        }

        public void setDate(String date) {
            this.date = date;
        }
    }

    public static class CreatedAt {
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("timezone")
        private String timezone;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("timezone_type")
        private int timezoneType;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("date")
        private String date;

        public String getTimezone() {
            return timezone;
        }

        public void setTimezone(String timezone) {
            this.timezone = timezone;
        }

        public int getTimezoneType() {
            return timezoneType;
        }

        public void setTimezoneType(int timezoneType) {
            this.timezoneType = timezoneType;
        }

        public String getDate() {
            return date;
        }

        public void setDate(String date) {
            this.date = date;
        }
    }
}
```

Now access inner class like this. Please check below.

```
ArrayList<TempClass> item = new ArrayList<>();

item.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getUpdatedAt().getDate();//here access the UpdatedAt class object method. 

item.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getCreatedAt().getDate();// here access the CreatedAt class object method.
```